# Pass Content and Attributes from 2 different Processors to InvokeHttp Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Here is what i am trying to do

1. Get a file and encode it to base 64
2. Login to API and get OAUTH token for subsequent API calls (Since Invoke HTTP doesnt take a body so i have to pass a body using GenerateFlow processor before that)

Both Steps 1 and 2 are interchangeable

3. Now i need the token from the login call as Header value and Base64 encoded file as the body to the next Invoke Processor.

The problem is i am not able to connect the flows 1 and 2 so i can take them to step 3 where i need to invoke another API using the data from the 2. Both GetFile and GenerateFlow are source processors.

Here is what i am thinking, to somehow convert the content to attribute. Since the file is encoded in base64, is there a way i can convert that content to attribute? i am trying to but the content is just random text, i am not sure what param to look for or what i need to put that to. is there a way to say convert whatever is in the content to an attribute say filecontent="all the flow-content"

[nifi-flow-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3PRF.png)

[Base 64 encoded content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSjL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved my issue for now. There may be other better ways but this one worked.
Start the flow with

> GetFile>>Base64Encode>>ExtractText>>ReplaceText>>Login>>continue

with rest of the flow

The trick that work was to place the `ReplaceText` so it can grab the entire base64 encoded content and place it in an attribute. then `ReplaceText` will replace the entire content with the body of the login processor.
Now i have both login token and base 64 encoded file which i can send to my next processors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. First trigger both flow fro mthe same generateflowfie >> updateattribute(create common attribute to be used in merge correlation).
2. Do your work
3. Use MergeContent - keep all unique attribute - Set correlaion using the common attribute set in out first step.

Comment: I dont think GenerateFlow can be linked to GetFile somehow, since both are source processors